# Leaflet+D3 how to show multiple layers as plane with markers on it

Tags: leaflet, d3, 3d-map

I'm trying to draw map which looks similar to 3 Dimensional. It has 3 layers bottom most is base layer which is OSM map layer. 2 and 3 is svg layer. as shown in below diagram, I'm able to tilt/rotate the map to using css transform functionality. However I'm not able to give background color to svg element using d3 and there by fill the layer with custom color to represent a plane and even not able to transform the polygon lat/long to x,y and z(offset) on svg using d3 such that polygon looks like placed on corresponding layer. Below is the digram I'm trying to achieve.

[image]